# Can I assign a value from ReactJS Native to a Swift global variable? If so, how?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, ffi, reactjs-native

Is there any (straightforward) way to assign the value of a Swift global variable (of double_t type) from ReactJS Native JavaScript? Or (scaling back from an XY question) is there any other way to make a (floating-point) Number computed in ReactJS Native JavaScript, and access it from a .swift file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. At least not directly.

You can make your own [Native Module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content) that React Native can call on and get data from. This allows you to write some native code that has a method that can be called to deliver the info you need. Then you write some javascript to that calls that method.

Note the [Swift Specific documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#exporting-swift) here.

Comment: Thank you. ReactJS Native looks promising, but what I've found in my digging and asking so far suggests I would be wiser to see what I can get from Swift. I appreciate the note, and what I have done in ReactJS JavaScript so far looks like it *should* be portable at least to Swift.